# aws sdk for go forbidden but aws cli works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk, httpforbiddenhandler

We are using aws cli and it works perfectly, we can create taskdefinitions, create services, etc. The problem comes when we want to use the sdk for go. We always get a forbidden. We have tried to use a new empty session, a session specifying the region, asuming roles... nothing works. Does anyone know how we could solve it?

We have tried many things: 
- setting a new config when creating a new session:

```
Config: aws.Config{
    CredentialsChainVerboseErrors: aws.Bool(true),
    Credentials: credentials.NewEnvCredentials(),
    Region: aws.String("eu-west-1"),
}
```

- asuming several roles in the session.NewSessionWithOptions:

```
AssumeRoleTokenProvider: stscreds.StdinTokenProvider
```

Nothing works. We always get a forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

By default the cli uses your credentials from ~/.aws/credentials and region from ~/.aws/config. Try this to create your session:

```
sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
}))
```