# How to use IAM User credentials with Go AWS SDK v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk

I'm getting **IAM User** credentials dynamically and **I want to use the credentials I generated using the program to create a session/client**. Not the shared credentials methods. Through code. I tried this and I know its not the right way, it doesn't work anyway. Anyone has any idea how to do this properly?

```
    staticCred := aws.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey, secretKey, "")
    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic("unable to load SDK config, " + err.Error())
    }
    cfg.Credentials = staticCred
    cfg.Region = aws.String("ap-southeast-1")
    fmt.Println(cfg)

    svc := ssm.New(cfg)

    req := svc.StartSessionRequest(&ssm.StartSessionInput{
        Target: aws.String(instanceId),
    })
    fmt.Println(req)

    resp, _ := req.Send(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error sending ssm request : %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
```

Comment: You want to try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524922/5766794

Comment: i need to create a session with the credentials that a generated with the program, not using the credentials file or environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for sometime till the credentials actually work. I'm using **Hashicorp Vault** to make the credentials btw.
I'm using

> GetCallerIdentityRequest(&sts.GetCallerIdentityInput{})

to check if they are alive yet. 
If anyone has better solutions for both please feel free to comment